# React-router: Refreshing the child page contents with hashHistory.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on an SPA that uses the react router like so:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Base}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="features/:id" component={Single} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

I have a component attached to the **Base** that is supposed to update the contents of **Single** via:

```
hashHistory.push(`features/${val.value}`);
```

The page url updates successfully but once I am in the child Route, the change to hashHistory doesn't cause the child state to update. Any ideas how I can reload the content here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [`componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops). This will respond to prop changes for all `render`s except the initial one. Recall that everything coming from the router is really just a prop.

```
// Example: the feature id changed in the url
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.params.id !== nextProps.params.id) {
    this.setState(...);
  }
}
```